# vb Could not load file or assembly Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, installation

I made application in vb 2010. And everything works great at mine computer. I made release and publish the application when i sen!

[Pictures](http://pokit.org/get/?758f78f3748fb1ea1201316e67b35bc1.jpg)

```
Could not load file or assembly Mysql...
```

Also is there any way i can put net framework 4.5 to be installed with my application ?

Comment: the `MySQL` provider is not part of .NET; you will have to distribute it or have the user [download it](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

Comment: How can i distribute it with my application ?

Comment: @Plutonix also i distribute my app with inno installer if this may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include NET Framework by the following way. At least in Visual Basic 2010...

1. Through Project Tab you open Project properties.
2. Then in Publish Tab you Click Prerequisites Button.
3. There you can select the things you want to diistribute and the way they will be distributed.